# How to upgrade appengine-java-sdk installed in .gradle folder

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

When I build my Android Studio project, it says :

```
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.15
Timestamp: Tue Oct 21 21:33:59 EDT 2014
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.14
Timestamp: Thu Oct 16 16:07:33 EDT 2014
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SDK.
```

I noticed that there is an appengine-java-sdk in my .gradle folder in my home folder :

~/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.14

Do I have to download the latest AppEngine SDK from here :

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

or is there an easier way to update it from Android Studio?

Answer (score 5):

Change the version from gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
}
```

then click 'synch project'. It will automatically push IDE to download and install the version you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the built-in app-engine support, check your gradle dependencies for the back end.  For example, this is the `build.gradle` from a backend module in a simple project:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}
```

Update the version number for the SDK above and Gradle should be able to pull the correct version from Maven/JCentral.

Answer (score 1):

You don't update

> appengine-java-sdk installed in .gradle folder

You download a new version.When you do this, your `.gradle/appengine-sdk` folder looks like this:

[image]

As others have said, you simple download a new version by changing the version number in dependencies and perform project sync. ( You must have Internet connection)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven Then just update the pom.xml in your project tp the latest app engine sdk.

```
<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <appengine.target.version>1.9.32</appengine.target.version>
</properties>
```